# What is this purple flower in Hungary?

Tags: identification, flowers

This purple flower was photographed in the garden of an acquaintance and no one seemed to recognize it. Can anyone identify? (Sorry for the weird perspective on the photo, I didn't take it)

[image: Purple flower]

Comment: Check out Campanula latifolia - from the little that can be  seen in the photo, that's a strong possibility

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bellflower ([campanula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campanula)).

Of course this is a rather huge genus, but a more precise ID would require a better photo(s), showing more details like leaves, flower details and overall size and shape.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on its size,(fairly small) I'd say campanula rotundifolia, commonly know in Britain as harebell, found throughout Europe, from the Mediterranean to the Arctic.